# CSS file loads, but its content does not

Tags: html, css

I've linked properly my css file to the html intended, and when I check the sources on chrome, the file is being actually loaded but it has nothing inside, its totally blank. However, in my ide, the file has the actual code I want to implement.

Forgot the code:

HTML

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; }
    </style>
</head>
```

CSS inside static folder:

```
 .style1{
    width:38%; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right:4%;
 }
```

Comment: Would you please put the code (both HTML and CSS) here?

Comment: just check the file path that you have mentioned in html and the one you have on the ide and make sure you save it before you check it on the browser

Comment: @R.Mazarei Added, thanks

Comment: Where is the html part that uses this class? do you see the styles affect? If the file is blank, sometimes it means it is being blocked.

Comment: No, I dont see the styles affect, I just pasted the code where I call the css file.

Comment: In firefox, use CTRL+U combination to see the source code, then click on "static/styles.css", if you can see your css rules, then everything must be ok, if you get a "Not Found" message or 404 error, then this part : <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css"> is the problem.
based on the link to the css, you should have a folder/directory named "static" beside your html file, and inside it, you should have a "styles.css" file.

Comment: Did you just filled the CSS file? Refresh the page with CTRL + F5. It loads the website without cache files and downloads everything from the server again. Maybe the browser cached an old, empty version of your file.